# In Scheme, how can I take in and compare the first items of lists and sublists?

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I have zero experience in Scheme. I'm trying to take in this list:

```
(define disk 
  '("D" "main"
    (("F" "file1.txt" (30))
     ("F" "file2.txt" (11))
     ("D" "sub1"
          (("F" "file1.txt" (1234))
           ("F" "file2.txt" (2345))
           ("F" "file3.txt" (3456))))
     ("D" "sub2" 
          (("F" "file1.txt" (1234))
           ("F" "file2.txt" (2345))
           ("F" "file3.txt" (3456)))))))
```

I want to take in this list and compare "F" and "D" to find out if the sublist is a File or a Directory. I also have to run through the list recursively and add up all of the numbers at the end of each File.

However, I'm having trouble even taking in the list. Everyone online always writes their code like:

```
 (car '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

But I can't find one that actually takes in a premade list. This is the code I wrote:

```
(define (file? lst)
  (car '(disk)))

 (file? car '(disk)
```

But of course, it just sees "disk" as its own list and returns the first element of that list, which is just disk. I'm trying to get it to return "F" or "D" so I can make a step further in this project. Thanks!

Comment: `(car lst)`  ?  Quotes are just to make literal data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having trouble with the syntax of scheme, and more specifically how to refer to an argument. So, you write:

```
(define (file? lst)
  (car '(disk)))
```

The problem here is that you're not referring to the parameter.

To be more concrete: let's say that I asked a kid in math class to define a function that takes a number and multiplies it by three and adds one, and they wrote

f(x) = 3*4+1

Would that be correct, or incorrect?